# Variable substitution not working in shell scripting

Tags: bash

I am having a simple shell script . i am using jq to parse some json data. However it is not working. so the following is my shell script

```
#! /bin/sh

cat sample.json  | jq '. | select(.type=="Point" and .metric=="iterations") | .data.value' | jq -s add


COUNT=`cat sample.json`  | jq '. | select(.type=="Point" and .metric=="iterations") | .data.value' | jq -s add

echo "Value of Count: $Count"

TOTAL=$(cat sample.json)


COUNT_1=`$TOTAL | jq '. | select(.type=="Point" and .metric=="iterations") |.data.value' | jq -s add`

echo "Value of Count_1: $Count_1"
```

The output generated by my script is below

```
1
null
Value of Count:
test.sh: line 13: {"type":"Metric","data":{"name":"http_reqs","type":"counter","contains":"default","thresholds":[],"submetrics":null},"metric":"http_reqs"}: command not found
Value of Count_1:
```

I could see the variable COUNT_1 AND COUNT are not printed correctly . I would expect them to have value 1

Here's the `sample.json` i am using for this issue:

```json
{"type":"Metric","data":{"name":"http_reqs","type":"counter","contains":"default","thresholds":[],"submetrics":null},"metric":"http_reqs"} {"metric":"http_reqs","type":"Point","data":{"time":"2023-02-22T02:07:16.696166854Z","value":1,"tags":{"expected_response":"true","group":"","method":"GET","name":"http://172.19.0.4:30339/SccTestService/v1/id","proto":"HTTP/1.1","scenario":"default","status":"200","url":"http://172.19.0.4:30339/SccTestService/v1/id"}}} {"type":"Metric","data":{"name":"http_req_duration","type":"trend","contains":"time","thresholds":[],"submetrics":[{"name":"http_req_duration{expected_response:true}","suffix":"expected_response:true","tags":{"expected_response":"true"}}]},"metric":"http_req_duration"} {"metric":"http_req_duration","type":"Point","data":{"time":"2023-02-22T02:07:16.696166854Z","value":62.062662,"tags":{"expected_response":"true","group":"","method":"GET","name":"http://172.19.0.4:30339/SccTestService/v1/id","proto":"HTTP/1.1","scenario":"default","status":"200","url":"http://172.19.0.4:30339/SccTestService/v1/id"}}} {"type":"Metric","data":{"name":"http_req_blocked","type":"trend","contains":"time","thresholds":[],"submetrics":null},"metric":"http_req_blocked"} {"metric":"http_req_blocked","type":"Point","data":{"time":"2023-02-22T02:07:16.696166854Z","value":1.246508,"tags":{"expected_response":"true","group":"","method":"GET","name":"http://172.19.0.4:30339/SccTestService/v1/id","proto":"HTTP/1.1","scenario":"default","status":"200","url":"http://172.19.0.4:30339/SccTestService/v1/id"}}} {"type":"Metric","data":{"name":"http_req_connecting","type":"trend","contains":"time","thresholds":[],"submetrics":null},"metric":"http_req_connecting"} {"metric":"http_req_connecting","type":"Point","data":{"time":"2023-02-22T02:07:16.696166854Z","value":1.072056,"tags":{"expected_response":"true","group":"","method":"GET","name":"http://172.19.0.4:30339/SccTestService/v1/id","proto":"HTTP/1.1","scenario":"default","status":"200","url":"http://172.19.0.4:30339/SccTestService/v1/id"}}} {"type":"Metric","data":{"name":"http_req_tls_handshaking","type":"trend","contains":"time","thresholds":[],"submetrics":null},"metric":"http_req_tls_handshaking"} {"metric":"http_req_tls_handshaking","type":"Point","data":{"time":"2023-02-22T02:07:16.696166854Z","value":0,"tags":{"expected_response":"true","group":"","method":"GET","name":"http://172.19.0.4:30339/SccTestService/v1/id","proto":"HTTP/1.1","scenario":"default","status":"200","url":"http://172.19.0.4:30339/SccTestService/v1/id"}}} {"type":"Metric","data":{"name":"http_req_sending","type":"trend","contains":"time","thresholds":[],"submetrics":null},"metric":"http_req_sending"} {"metric":"http_req_sending","type":"Point","data":{"time":"2023-02-22T02:07:16.696166854Z","value":0.319471,"tags":{"expected_response":"true","group":"","method":"GET","name":"http://172.19.0.4:30339/SccTestService/v1/id","proto":"HTTP/1.1","scenario":"default","status":"200","url":"http://172.19.0.4:30339/SccTestService/v1/id"}}} {"type":"Metric","data":{"name":"http_req_waiting","type":"trend","contains":"time","thresholds":[],"submetrics":null},"metric":"http_req_waiting"} {"metric":"http_req_waiting","type":"Point","data":{"time":"2023-02-22T02:07:16.696166854Z","value":60.315417,"tags":{"expected_response":"true","group":"","method":"GET","name":"http://172.19.0.4:30339/SccTestService/v1/id","proto":"HTTP/1.1","scenario":"default","status":"200","url":"http://172.19.0.4:30339/SccTestService/v1/id"}}} {"type":"Metric","data":{"name":"http_req_receiving","type":"trend","contains":"time","thresholds":[],"submetrics":null},"metric":"http_req_receiving"} {"metric":"http_req_receiving","type":"Point","data":{"time":"2023-02-22T02:07:16.696166854Z","value":1.427774,"tags":{"expected_response":"true","group":"","method":"GET","name":"http://172.19.0.4:30339/SccTestService/v1/id","proto":"HTTP/1.1","scenario":"default","status":"200","url":"http://172.19.0.4:30339/SccTestService/v1/id"}}} {"type":"Metric","data":{"name":"http_req_failed","type":"rate","contains":"default","thresholds":[],"submetrics":null},"metric":"http_req_failed"} {"metric":"http_req_failed","type":"Point","data":{"time":"2023-02-22T02:07:16.696166854Z","value":0,"tags":{"expected_response":"true","group":"","method":"GET","name":"http://172.19.0.4:30339/SccTestService/v1/id","proto":"HTTP/1.1","scenario":"default","status":"200","url":"http://172.19.0.4:30339/SccTestService/v1/id"}}} {"type":"Metric","data":{"name":"data_sent","type":"counter","contains":"data","thresholds":[],"submetrics":null},"metric":"data_sent"} {"metric":"data_sent","type":"Point","data":{"time":"2023-02-22T02:07:16.696387685Z","value":102,"tags":{"group":"","scenario":"default"}}} {"type":"Metric","data":{"name":"data_received","type":"counter","contains":"data","thresholds":[],"submetrics":null},"metric":"data_received"} {"metric":"data_received","type":"Point","data":{"time":"2023-02-22T02:07:16.696387685Z","value":266,"tags":{"group":"","scenario":"default"}}} {"type":"Metric","data":{"name":"iteration_duration","type":"trend","contains":"time","thresholds":[],"submetrics":null},"metric":"iteration_duration"} {"metric":"iteration_duration","type":"Point","data":{"time":"2023-02-22T02:07:16.696387685Z","value":63.639606,"tags":{"group":"","scenario":"default"}}} {"type":"Metric","data":{"name":"iterations","type":"counter","contains":"default","thresholds":[],"submetrics":null},"metric":"iterations"} {"metric":"iterations","type":"Point","data":{"time":"2023-02-22T02:07:16.696387685Z","value":1,"tags":{"group":"","scenario":"default"}}}
```

Comment: `UUOC` aka [Useless Use Of Cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)

Comment: The backquote is used in the old-style command substitution, e.g. `foo=`command``. The `foo=$(command)` syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside `$()` is less surprising, and `$()` is easier to nest. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: @GillesQuénot I think that the OP is basically trying different things to attempt debugging, but they're missing the actual bugs because they're not being careful about case sensitivity. UUOC is just an attempt in frustration by OP to see what is happening the actual problem is typographical errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the output of a pipeline to be assigned to a variable, you have to include the whole pipeline into backticks, not just the first part of it.

```
COUNT=`cat sample.json | jq '. | select(.type=="Point" and .metric=="iterations") | .data.value' | jq -s add`
#                     ~                                                                                     ~
```

Also, it's better to use `$(...)` instead of `` `...` `` as they nest properly.

Moreover, no need to use `cat`: `jq` can take the file name as an argument or you can use redirection.

Finally, don't use upper case for variables. It should only be used for system vars.

```
count=$(< sample.json  jq '. | select(.type=="Point" and .metric=="iterations") | .data.value' | jq -s add)
```

Comment: Please, show him `$( )` and why a `UUOC` ?

Comment: i tried the following COUNT=$(cat sample.json  | jq '. | select(.type=="Point" and .metric=="iterations") | .data.value' | jq -s add)

echo "Value of Count: $Count" but still no luck

Comment: @StarbucksAdmin: You have the capitalisation of COUNT vs. $Count wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code including typographical errors

### Use `/bin/bash` if you mean `/bin/bash`

```
#!/bin/bash
```

### Use $() instead of `` and enclose the entire thing that you want to capture the standard output of:

```
COUNT=$(cat sample.json  | jq '. | select(.type=="Point" and .metric=="iterations") | .data.value' | jq -s add)
```

### Variables are case-sensitive (`$COUNT` is not `$Count`)

`echo "Value of Count:`<strike>`$Count"`</strike>`$COUNT`

### Typographical errors

Please be mindful of case-sensitivity of variables in shell

```
echo "Value of Count_1: $Count_1"
```

Will print nothing because `$COUNT_1` is not the same as `$Count_1`

## Corrected script

```bash
#!/bin/bash

cat sample.json | jq '. 
    | select(.type=="Point" and .metric=="iterations") 
    | [ .data.value ] | flatten | add
   '
```

You don't need to use `jq -s add` of course jq takes a file as input but you may be feeding it output of another process so I left the `cat sample.json` there which I think is a placeholder for piping in something else. If not then you can further simplify by

```bash
#!/bin/bash

jq '. 
    | select(.type=="Point" and .metric=="iterations") 
    | [ .data.value ] | flatten | add
   ' sample.json
```